# skip method calling inside a method body python unit test

Tags: python-unittest

I have a class A, which has two methods :

```py
def app1():
    ----some code-----
    app2() # line 3



def app2():
    ----some code---
```

here while writing unit test for above class, I am calling app1() method
but I want to skip the calling method app2() from app1() method.

```
class TestController(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app1() # its failing here(at line 3), because there is some DB setting inside app2() which i want to skip.
```

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about mocking

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from apps import app1


class App1Tests(TestCase):
    @patch('apps.app2')
    def test_app1(self, app2):
        app1()
        app2.assert_called_once_with()
```